# Measure and the intersection with an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E \subset \Re$ be measurable with $\mu(E) > 0$. Show that for
>   every $0 < \epsilon < 1$ there is an open interval $I$ such that
>   $\mu(E \bigcap I) > (1-\epsilon)\mu(I)$

Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$, $\mu(E)>0$. How would I start this?

Comment: If this is the Lebesgue integral, you could choose some interval $J$ such that $0 < \mu(E \cap J) < \infty$, and then look at $F(x) = \int_{(-\infty,x]} 1_{E \cap J}$. Note that $1_{E \cap J}$ is integrable, hence $F'$ exists a.e. Compute the value of $F'$ and use this to obtain the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $F\subset[a,b]$ be measurable set of positive measure, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open interval $I$ such that $\mu(F\cap I)>(1-\varepsilon)\mu(I)$

**Proof.** Assume there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all open interavals $I$ holds $\mu(F\cap I)\leq (1-\varepsilon)\mu(I)$. From definition of measure it follows that there exists a family of open intervals $\{J_k:k=1,\ldots,m\}$ such that
$$
F\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^n J_k\quad\text{and}\quad\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu(J_k)<\mu(F)(1+\varepsilon)
$$
From the assumption above we get
$$
\mu(F)=\mu\left(F\cap\bigcup_{k=1}^n J_k\right)\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu(F\cap J_k)\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(1-\varepsilon)\mu(J_k)=(1-\varepsilon^2)\mu(F)
$$
Contradiction.

**Theorem.** Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set of positive measure, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open interval $I$ such that $\mu(F\cap I)>(1-\varepsilon)\mu(I)$

**Proof.** Fix $\varepsilon>0$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, denote $F_n=E\cap[n,n+1)$. Then $\mu(E)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mu(F_n)$. Since $\mu(E)>0$, there exists some  $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu(F_n)>0$. By previous lemma there exists an open interval $I$ such that $\mu(F_n\cap I)>(1-\varepsilon)\mu(I)$. Hence
$$
\mu(E\cap I)\geq\mu(F_n\cap I)>(1-\varepsilon)\mu(I)
$$